# Java variable number of arguments for a method

Tags: java, methods, arguments, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

Is it possible to declare a method that will allow a variable number of parameters ?

What is the symbolism used in the definition that indicate that the method should allow a variable number of parameters?

**Answer:** varargs

Comment: Since its homework, we don't want to know your question, we just want to know you are learning.

Answer (score 314):

That's correct. You can find more about it in [the Oracle guide on varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Here's an example:

```
void foo(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

which can be called as

```
foo("foo"); // Single arg.
foo("foo", "bar"); // Multiple args.
foo("foo", "bar", "lol"); // Don't matter how many!
foo(new String[] { "foo", "bar" }); // Arrays are also accepted.
foo(); // And even no args.
```

Comment: Is it possible to do various type of paramteres? e.g. (String...strs, int... ints). What about just any type of argument in any order?

Comment: @trusktr: if you want any object, just use `Object...`.

Comment: @trusktr No, primitives are not objects. There is a great explanation of the difference here: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/

Comment: @Richard: Using `Object... args` will work with primitives because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: How would you check the number of arguments?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro : I assume that the arguments are handled like an array, so you could probably simply do `varargs.length`

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it's possible:

```
public void myMethod(int... numbers) { /* your code */ }
```

Comment: not precised enough to understand

Answer (score 17):

```
Variable number of arguments
```

It is possible to pass a variable number of arguments to a method. However, there 
are some restrictions:

- The variable number of parameters must all be the same type
- They are treated as an array within the method
- They must be the last parameter of the method

To understand these restrictions, consider the method, in the following code snippet, used to return the largest integer in a list of integers:

```
private static int largest(int... numbers) {
     int currentLargest = numbers[0];
     for (int number : numbers) {
        if (number > currentLargest) {
            currentLargest = number;
        }
     }
     return currentLargest;
}
```

source Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 7 Programmer Study Guide 2012

Answer (score 14):

For different types of arguments, there is **3-dots** :

```
public void foo(Object... x) {
    String myVar1  = x.length > 0 ? (String)x[0]  : "Hello";
    int myVar2     = x.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt((String) x[1]) : 888;
}
```

Then call it

```
foo("Hii"); 
foo("Hii", 146);
```

for security, use like this: 
    
`if (!(x[0] instanceof String)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("..."); }`

> The main drawback of this approach is that if optional parameters are of different types you lose static type checking. 
>   Please, see [**more variations**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994104/2377343) .

Answer (score 6):

Yup...since Java 5: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes Java allows `vargs` in method parameter .

```
public class  Varargs
{
   public int add(int... numbers)
   { 
      int result = 1; 
      for(int number: numbers)
      {
         result= result+number;  
      }  return result; 
   }
}
```