# Function with unknown amount of variables

Tags: java, loops, variadic-functions

I saw someone creating a function that has an unknown number of arguments:

```
public static double calculator(double ... value){
    double result=0d;

    for(int i=0;i<?;i++){
        result+=value;
    }

    return result
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a `for` loop that will run the number of times as the number of arguments entered so:

```
double calc = calculator(1,2,3,4,5)
```

this will make the for loop run 5 times.

Comment: `?` --> `value.length`. And your `+= value` won't work, you can't add a `double[]` to a `double`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java variable number or arguments for a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330942/java-variable-number-or-arguments-for-a-method)

Comment: Your parameter is named wrong. Should be `values`, not `value`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally, the `value` is an array, so you can treat it as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    result += value[i];
}
```

Comment: Worked, thank you very much! I can mark this as the answer only in 11 minutes from now ;)

Answer (score 2):

The ellipsis operator (`...`) is just syntactic sugaring for an array. In other words, the method itself interprets the arguments as follows:

```
public static double calculator(double[] value)
```

Once you understand that, the `for` loop becomes obvious - you just need to iterate up to `value.length`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <value.length; i++) {
    result += value[i];
}
```

Or better yet, just use an enhanced `for` loop:

```
for (v : value) {
    result += v;
}
```

Comment: Wait.. Now when I'm trying to use 
`public static double calculator(double[] value)`
it doesn't work with int's..

Comment: The ellipsis operator is much more forgiving - it promotes each value separately. If you want to actually change the signature to receive a `double[]` (redundant, IMHO), you'll have to pass a `double[]` instance, even if you are filling its elements with `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could use advance for loop (a.k.a for each loop) as below:

```
for(int element : value){
    result+=element;
}
```

Its same as:

```
for(int i = 0;i < value.length; i++){
     result+=value[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't really like for each loops, is there an advantage of using them? and how exactly do they work?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use for each loop,

```
 for (double d : value) {

 }
```