# Open parameters in java

Tags: java, function, parameters

How do declare and use parameters in java when not knowing the number and type of paramenters that will be passed...

I want to declare a method something like...

```
static void method1( ... ) for ( i: parameters ) print( i )
// or
static void method1( int a, ... ) for ( f=a; f < parameters.count(); f++) print( parameters[ i] );
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java variable number or arguments for a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330942/java-variable-number-or-arguments-for-a-method)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass exactly one `vararg` parameter per method. It has to be the last one and you have to specify the type. The `vararg`-Parameter will be passed into the method ass array.

```
public void method(int a, String... varargParam){
    for (int f=a; f < varargParam.length; f++){
        System.out.println( varargParam[f] );
    }
}
```

You can call the method like this

```
method(2, "test1", "test2");
method(2, "test1", "test2", "test3");
method(2, new String[]{"test1","test2"});
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks... that's what i was lookin' for,,,

Answer (score 2):

```
public void method(Object... objs){}
```

This will take any number of arguments of unknown type.

Comment: I think as boxing is automatic this will work for most scenarios,,, thx!