# Constructor with variable number of arguments in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, variadic-functions

I would like to know how constructors with variable arguments work. Here is an example :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VehicleCompany {
private List<Vehicle> vehicles= new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

private void VehicleCompany (Vehicle... vehicles) {
 //how to complete it?
}
```

Which way is the easier to do it? I found that I can copy the argument`taxis` into another `list` or use a `for-loop` but didn't how to do since `this.taxis.size()` is 0.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `vehicles` will be an array of `Vehicle` objects (just like `Vehicle[] vehicles`)

Comment: I think you'll find your answer in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330942/java-variable-number-or-arguments-for-a-method

Comment: `ArrayList` work the best for me so I can't use an array

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` may help.

Comment: Try [Collections.addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-).

Comment: 1) Constructors with variable arguments work the same way as all other methods in Java with variable arguments. 2) What `taxis`? 3) What does "this.taxis.size() is 0" have to do with copying from parameter to field? The field will grown as needed. It's what an `ArrayList` does.

Comment: `this.vehicles.addAll(Arrays.asList(vehicles));`

Answer (score 2):

A vararg is effectively converted into an array.  So you can convert it to a list with `Arrays.asList()` as you would with any other array.