# Does java support generic method support all kinds of argument input?

Tags: java, generics, hystrix, fallback

I wanna code some method for hystrix default fallback methods, for example:

```
//declaration
public void voidDefaultFallback(generic argument list) {
    return;
}

public int intDefaultFallback(generic argument list) {
    return 0;
}

public Object nullDefaultFallback(generic argument list) {
    return null;
}
//invocation
nullDefaultFallback("a", "b");
nullDefaultFallback("a", 0);
nullDefaultFallback("a", 0, "abc");
```

does java support such generic method?

Comment: I'm not clear understand what you exactly mean by `generic argument list`. Your examples could be described by several ways: `K, V...`, `K...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java variable number or arguments for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330942/java-variable-number-or-arguments-for-a-method)

Comment: pass argument list object with your method

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that with this argument in method

```
public void method (Object ... objects){
        for(Object obj : objects){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

It's called **varargs** , you can find more info [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
nullDefaultFallback(Object...args);
```

Answer (score 0):

For different return types with same method names you need to specify different method signatures. For example:

```
public void m(K...) {...}
public int m(K...) {...}
```

is not valid case, but, for example:

```
public void m(K){...}
public int m(K, K) {...}
```

will work fine