# Unnecessary string in a method (overload methods)

Tags: java

How do I make a method that does not require an objects, but if there is one it would use it!

Like this

```
void cls(String source){
        if(source.isEmpty()){
            source = "Unknown source";
        }
        output.setText("Screen cleared from " + source);
    }
```

And later when I call this I could do

```
cls();
```

but it throws an error because it needs a string

```
cls("string");
```

but I want for both to work!

Comment: overload your `cls` method

Comment: Note, you may want to give your method distinct meaningful names rather than overloading.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline not neccesarily, it looks like common cls command to clear a screen (also noted in the output.setText("___") message).

Comment: To last editor: adding *How to overload* in title would make the question to be closed. In its current state, it shows lack of knowledge from OP about how to accomplish this task.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters) is related and might help OP understand Java's limitations as far as optional arguments within a single method definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use two methods with the same name but different signatures [(that's called overloading)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

```
void cls() {
    // ???
}

void cls(String source){
    if(source.isEmpty()){
        source = "Unknown source";
    }
    output.setText("Screen cleared from " + source);
}
```

or [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs):

```
void cls(String... sources){
    if (sources.length > 0) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but what if I have void `cls(String source, boolean isAllowed){}`

Comment: I want both string source and boolean isAllowed to be unnecessary!

Comment: @donemanuel You can "chain" overloaded methods together for as many arguments as you want. Just have your no-args method call the full version, with default arguments. `void cls() { cls("Unknown source", false); }` or whatever else you want for your default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you can create two methods. something like this:

```
void cls(String source) {...}

void cls() {
    return cls("Unknown source");
}
```

now you can call cls with or without the String parameter