# OrderBy + sum() + BooleanExpression

Tags: java, querydsl

I've got two entities: Category and Product with one-to-many relation.

How can I order categories by number of their products, with price greater than 100? Something like (this doesn't work):

```
query.from(category).leftJoin(category.products,
    product).orderBy(product.price.gt(100).count().desc()).list(category)
```

Comment: Possibly related? Might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090098/how-do-you-specify-multi-column-orderspecifier-for-use-in-springdata-and-queryds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
query.from(category).leftJoin(category.products, product).where(product.price.gt(100)).
groupBy(category).orderBy(product.count().desc()).list(category);
```

I tried a variation of this on my current dataset and it produced reasonable results.