# Java, non fixed parameters for method

Tags: java

Im beginner at Java. There is a method:

```
public void method (int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4)
```

depend on the circumstances, I sometimes need to pass parameters to [param1], or [param2,param4], it depends on an XML setting. But its not that simple to simply pass (0, desiredValue1, desiredValue2, 0) - the best would be to pass an associate array to define the parameter name and its value. I heard this kind of job is done with reflections.

Comment: You could simply use overloaded versions of your function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters

Comment: Use a `Map`. But I would first rethink your design, to see if this is absolutely the only option.

Comment: While there is more than one technical solution to this problem, I think you should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an array :

```
public void method (int[] params)
```

This would still require that you allocate an array of n elements, where n is the max number of potential parameters, and could be wasteful for a large n. It also requires that you have a default empty value (such as 0), that tells you a certain position in the array has no value.

```
   int[] params = new int[13];
   params[0] = value1;
   params[3] = value4;
   params[4] = value5;
   method (params);
```

Or you could pass a List :

```
public void method (List<Integer> params)
```

Or you could pass a Map :

```
public void method (Map<Integer,Integer> params)
```

The latter would be the most eficient if you have a large number of optional parameters, and you want to pass just few of them :

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
map.put (5, value5);
map.put (13, value13);
method (map);
```

Comment: ok, yea, still dont know how to call my original method (int a, int b, int c, int d)

Comment: @JohnSmith Using the Map approach, you'll do : `Map map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); map.put(1,first);map.put(2,second);map.put(3,third);map.put(4,fourth);method(map);` where first,second,third and fourth are the parameters passed to the method.

Answer (score 3):

Not reflection. Use overloading:

```
public void method (int param1)
public void method (int param2, int param4)
```

If you really need more than 4 up to all 15 combinations, think of alternatives.

```
public void method (Integer param1, Integer param2, Integer param3, Integer param4)
```

This will let you pass in null for absent parameters.

A Map is another option.

A better parsing and interpretation of your XML might result in an even easier solution.

**Later**

You can, of course, resort to a kind of "tagged" storage for your parameters.

```
class Parameter<T> {
    String name;
    T value; ... 
    Parameter( String name, T value ){...}
}

void method( Parameter<?>... parameters ){
    for( Parameter<?> par: parameters ){
        switch( par.getName() ){
        case "param1": //...
        //...
        }
    }
}

method( new Parameter<Integer>( "param1", 42 ),
        new Parameter<Double>( "param3", 3.14 ) );
```

If you don't need genericity, simply use int in all relevant places.

Comment: thanks, but I dont think so: so, even if I have:
void method (int a, int b)
void method (int c, int b)
a call like (1,2) - which method to run?

Comment: Then you'll have to resort to Integer, where null indicates a missing value, or a Map. - But in dozens of years of programming, I've met a situation like this only once (IIRC); so I'm not convinced that you really need to go that way. Even if you indicate, somehow, which combinaton is "active", you burden the method "method" with the task of deciding which is which. The design is questionable.

Comment: @JohnSmith  Maybe you'd like to try "tagged" values.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the map instance:

```
public void method(final Map<String, Integer> params) {
    // code omitted
}
```

In the method body you'll have some `if-else` statements to extract and use parameters which were passed.

**Upd.:** Probably the better way would be to use the map from enums which will be used to name the params to their actual values:

```
enum MethodParameters { Param1, Param2, Param3 };
public void method(final Map<MethodParameters, Integer> params) {
    // code omitted
}
```

This way you don't need to write the parameters names more the once, so you won't get a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to using a Map you can use a varargs and parse it yourself, although It would be better to use overloaded functions or a better parsing of your XML. I would be very very careful doing it this way or the Map way; you should do a lot of error checking on the params that are being passed in.

```
private void printParams(Object... params) {
    for (Object param : params) System.out.println(param);
}
```

Comment: How I can understand from the varargs itself that I've passed in 1-st, 2-nd and 4-th parameters of my function, and not the 2-nd, 3-rd and 4-th?

Comment: ok, yea, still dont know how to call my original method (int a, int b, int c, int d)