# Generalizing a Function on Files in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, nio, generalization

I'm attempting to write a Concordance program in Java using JDK 8 (to relearn the language). So far, I have the following (package name omitted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static Map<String,Integer> generateConcordance(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Map<String,Integer> concordance = new HashMap<>();

        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            for (String word : line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")) {
                concordance.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
            }
        }

        return concordance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("invalid operation - you must specify an input file");
        } else {
            try {
                Map<String, Integer> concordance = generateConcordance(args[0]);
                concordance.forEach((key,value) -> System.out.println(key + "\t" + value));
            } catch (IOException error) {
                System.err.println("I/O error - unable to read the file: " + args[0]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This works, but I'd like to generalize the implementation to be able to read input from `System.in` if no arguments are passed. Is it possible to modify the input to the function `generateConcordance` to allow it to be applied to either a named file or `System.in`?

Comment: Why not overload generateConcordance() with no params and give it the default behavior with System.in?

Comment: btw, about optional params in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters

Comment: I'd like my implementation to be as elaboration tolerant as possible. The algorithm behind `generateConcordance` ought not change if I'm reading a user specified file or `System.in` (which is basically the analogue to `stdin` in C).

Comment: yes so... I don't understand what is wrong, usually you would use optional parameters no?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand your suggestion. What I'm basically attempting to do is to see if I can generalize the outer for loop: `for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)))` to operate on either `System.in` or `fileName`. Reading the documentation I don't see a straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: You asked how to generalize the implementation, of the function, no the loop. So if you want to change only the loop, I don't think it's possible. It's why I sugested you to overload your method or use a trick for emulate optional parameter on your function. Finaaly you will be able to call your method with or without parameter and have the good behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of refactoring, and using `Stream<String>` this should be pretty straightforward.  You could try the following (untested):

```
public class Main {

  private static final Pattern wordBreak = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");

  public static Map<String, Long> generateConcordance(Stream<String> lines) {
    return lines
      .flatMap(wordBreak::splitAsStream)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
  }

  public static Map<String, Long> generateConcordance(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      return generateConcordance(lines);
    }
  }

  public static Map<String, Long> generateConcordance(InputStream in) {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return generateConcordance(new BufferedReader(reader).lines());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
      generateConcordance("SomeRandomFile.txt");
      generateConcordance(System.in);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I would do.

Comment: You can also do `lines.flatMap(Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")::splitAsStream)...` to compile the regex just once.  Or store the compiled pattern in a constant and then `lines.flatMap(wordBreak::splitAsStream)...`

Comment: It's good to close your IO streams. Currently they are not closed automatically.

Comment: I don't think you would want to close the `InputStream` in the `generateConcordance(...)` method.  To me it would seem more logical to do this in the caller, where it was opened, probably using try-with-resources as an ownership thing in case the caller wanted to rewind a `FileInputStream` (for example) and do something else with it.  Unfortunately closing the wrappers (`InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`) closes the underlying stream too.

Comment: @msandiford: I agree about `generateConcordance(InputStream in)`, but it's created and not closed in `Map<String, Long> generateConcordance(String fileName)` method. See [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) documentation.

Comment: Generally, I appreciate structuring code but splitting such a simple operation into four methods merely consisting of one or two lines does *not* add to readability. `generateConcordance(Files.lines(Paths.get("SomeRandomFile.txt")));` and `generateConcordance(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines());` will do, maybe with some added local variables which are required for a proper `try(…) {}` statement anyway.