# Overriding a method with more parameters in java?

Tags: java, oop, overriding, overloading

I have a base class with a method called `execute` :

```
class A {
    public execute(int a){}
}
```

I also have a class B, which extends A, but the `execute` method needs more parameters:

Currently, my solution is using optional parameters :

```
class B extends A {
    public execute(int a, Object... parameters){
        long b = (long)parameters[0];
        boolean c = (boolean)parameters[1];
        ....
    }
}
```

This would still be ugly because I must cast on parameters. Are there other options for this situation?

Comment: Are you expecting a fixed number of parameters for `execute()` ?

Comment: See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters) by Vitalii Fedorenko, that lists all possible options.

Comment: @Atri : i don't need fixed number of parameters, i want to call through by base class. Ex :  A a = MyFactory.getInstance(...) , a.execute(...)

Answer (score 1):

you can add an `execute(int a, int b)` in B, but it won't override the `execute(int a)` method, it will overload it. Both method will be callable on an instance of `B`.

Comment: Yes it is fine if i use an instance of B, but in my case i use a instance of base class (A).

Answer (score 1):

This would break the OO paradigm. The L in solid stands for Liskov substitution principle.

The principle applied for you example is that B should behave as A.

A better solution would be to injects those parameters via the constructor and have an execute without any parameters.

```
class A {
    int a;
    public A(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public execute(){ // do something with a}
}

class B {
   int a;
   long b;
   boolean c;

    public B (int a, long b, boolean c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b; 
        this.c = c;
    }

    public execute(){ // do something with a, b and c}

}
```

Comment: but how to inject parameters when B need more parameters than A?

Comment: A and B would have their own constructors, having exactly the parameters they need.

Comment: Yes , but in my case i use a factory to create instance of base class A.

Comment: Can you post more code, I'm not sure that I'm following?