# How to call a function of 3 argument with only 2 argument?

Tags: java

I came across a question in **Java** interview where he asked me:
How to call a function say `add(int a, int b, boolean value)` with only passing two arguments like `add(int a, int b)`.
I was not aware about the same, and ask him for some hint then he replied me:

Go and read the following concept

```
Integer a;

int a;
```

Now my question is How the hint is related with the question and how can we achieve the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without providing a two-argument overload which invokes the three-argument overload (e.g. using `true` as the value for the 3rd parameter), you can't.

Comment: "How the hint is related with the question" Absolutely no idea. The hint that you've given doesn't make sense.

Comment: He asks something impossible, imply that he expects a creative answer. .... I will answer "My real-life solution for this problem is to use C++ instead of Java. (default parameter)  If you hire me, I will revolutionize your company to use C++ instead."

Comment: You can go with void add(Object... parameters) :-)

Comment: @javaLover: why C++, use Kotlin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java optional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You just cant break the methods signature, you will need to Overload the method 
and reduce/remove the paramters you just dont need/want

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by using the [wrapper and boxing concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

For example in your case you can create another method to receive two parameters and then do something like this:

```
add(int a, int b){
    Boolean c = null;
    add(a, b, c);
}
```

Or with an int value:

```
add(int a, boolean c){
    Integer b = null;
    add(a, b, c);
}
```

In that way you can change the primitive to its wrapper class... however, in the call it will throw and exception...

The reason is the auto-unboxing of the `Integer b = null` into a `int`. To unbox, the JVM will call `int Integer.intValue()` on a `null` value. To correct this exception, the solution is to prevent any unboxing, so the method needs to work with the wrappers classes. Here is the method :

```
add(Integer a, Integer b, Boolean c){
    //...
}
```

Since the parameter are not primitive, there is no need to try unboxing the `null` value. But this is needed inside of the method like any Object parameter. You still need to do some `null` check before using any `nullable` value. So you can't expect `a + b` to return something if `b` is null.

Comment: This will throw a NPE on each call since the JVM will tried to call `Boolean.booleanValue()` to get the primitive form on a null instance. (Same with the Integer).

Comment: Well... maybe is not so useless at all... It could works as a bad example ;)

Comment: Don't, just end with the method signature using the wrapper type to be usable ;) with explanation

Comment: @AxelH I will appreciate if you help me to improve this answer ;)

Comment: here is the idea. I let you see what you can do with the explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter don't exist in java, but you can reproduce this easily with overloading.

```
public int add(int a, int b){
    return this.add(a, b, true);
}

public int add(int a, int b, boolean value){
    return value ? ( a + b) : (a - b);
}
```

This boolean is "optionnal" with a default value of `true`.

So this can be use like:

```
add(1, 2);           // 3
add(1, 2, false);    // -1
```

This seems to be the same method but this is actually an overloading, one calling an other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Varargs, but you need to change the position of the boolean.

```
private void add(boolean a, int ... b){

}
```

You can invoke it like this

```
add(true, 1, 2);
add(false, 1);
add(true);
```

The varargs are optional and the data type is an array of the type.

If you need to use different types, you can use an array of objects. Object ... b.

Or you can define the array directly

```
private void add(int[] b, boolean a){

}
```

In this case you always have 2 params.

```
a = {1, 2};
add(a, true);
```

Comment: I like this solution, I use it a lot when I have to many optionnal (5+ overloading is messy) but this is restrictive on type (or need casting)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like this case: [Java optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters)

The fourth post explains each solution you can do.