# Function which can accept one or two parameter but not more than two

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a method which should accept minimum one and maximum two parameters. **First parameter is must but second is optional**.

I've tried following

```
myFunction(String param1, String param2){

}
```

But in this case both parameter need to be passed, which I don't want.

```
myFunction(String... params){
}
```

In this case it can accept more than two parameters also, which also I don't want.

Could someone please tell if it's accomplished in java?

Comment: I think it's not easy in java. You can achieve this type of behavior using function overloading with two methods and different arguments.

Comment: @SandeepKokate: I'm not sure in what way that counts as "not easy" to be honest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overload the method:

```
myFunction(String param1){
  ...
}

myFunction(String param1, String param2){
  ...
}
```

Consider making the "one parameter version" invoke the other version with a default value for the second parameter to simplify things.

Comment: This could be done, however in this case I need to duplicate my whole logic.

Comment: @MehrajMalik: In most cases, you'd just make the single-parameter overload call the two-parameter overload with a default value. No duplication needed. If you need to know which overload was called, create a third private method that the first two call, with three parameters: `param1`, `param2`, `param2UserSupplied` (the last being a boolean) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

In this exact case, since both possible parameters are strings, you could refactor your method to accept an array of strings, and then validate inside the method, e.g.

```
void myMethod (String... params) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (params == null || params.length < 1 ||
        params.length > 2 || params[0] == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong no. of arguments");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By overloading methods, you can achieve this with the following:

```
void foo(String param1, String param2) {
    // your logic here
}

void foo(String param1) {
    foo(param1, DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_PARAM2);
}
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994104/5771446) for a complete overview of what is possible with optional arguments within Java.

Answer (score 0):

Maby will good to use overload approach?
create two methods with same name but wit different attribute numbers

```
myFunction(param1)
myFunction(para1,param2)
```

Also, you can move the same logic from on abstract level, and use them on your **myFunction()**.