# calling method with Optional parameter in Java 8

Tags: java

I have the following method

```
public static Boolean test(String str, Optional<Boolean> test) {


}
```

but if I try to call it like

```
test("hello")
```

I get an error that the method requires two parameters.

Shouldn't the Optional parameter allow to me call the test method without providing the Optional parameter?

Comment: No, Java always requires the correct number of parameters.

Comment: No, Optional means it is expecting Optional object

Comment: `test("hello", Optional.empty());` - - `Optional` is a poor substitute for overloading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters)

Comment: That is not what `Optional` means here. `Optional` is another type of Java object...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Optional` is not a optional parameter as `var-args` is.
`Optional` is a container object which may or may not contain a non-null value.

So you could invoke the method as  :

```
test("...", Optional.of(true));
```

or

```
test("...", Optional.empty());
```

Note that with `var-args` :

```
public static Boolean test(String str, Boolean... test) {    
 //...
}
```

this would be valid :

```
test("hello")
```

But var-args **is not the correct way** to pass an optional parameter as it conveys **0 or more** objects and not **0 or 1** object.

Method overload is better :

```
public static Boolean test(String str, Boolean test) {
 // ...
}

public static Boolean test(String str) {
 // ...
}
```

In some other cases, the `@Nullable` constraints (JSR-380)  may also be interesting.

Comment: Note that `...` means `0 or more`, which makes `test` a `Boolean[]` and more than 1 `Boolean` can be passed into this method.

Comment: I wouldn't equate varargs with optional parameters. The appropriate thing to do here, if you don't want to pass the parameter, is to define an overload.

Comment: @Andy Turner I agree too. My last sentence conveys that. About the overload, it is a way indeed. And in some other cases`@Nullable` may be a good alternative too.

Comment: @davidxxx it doesn't convey it. If you want to say to use an overload to pass 0 or 1 parameters, say that, and show an example; and ditch the varargs stuff, or at least put it below the overloads stuff.

Comment: @Andy Turner Agree again. Thrown out or almost.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **no**.
`Optional` is a class and in Java you must pass the exact number of parameters to a method just like it is defined.

The only exception is when you put `...` after the class object name in the method declaration.

```
public String test (String X, String... Y) { }
```

Which makes the second parameter be `either zero or more`.

Comment: To be more precise: `Optional` is a class *like any other*. It is not defined in the language specification, and thus it is not handled in any way that is special.

Comment: @AndyTurner Exactly, good point! As a method parameter, it is handled in the same way as either another class or a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static Boolean test(String str, Boolean ... test) {}
```

it will work with you