# Is it possible to make a generic functional interface with optional parameter(s)?

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-11

I'm trying to create a functional interface in Java with a single method (of course) that can take any type of parameter(s) and return any data type (*i.e.* a generic method).

This is what I have so far:

**Calculator.java**

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T n1, T... n2); //this is where the optional parameter comes in
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator<Integer> addition = (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2; //this gives an error
}
```

The error says:

> bad operand types for binary operator '+'

- Is it possible to create a generic functional interface with optional parameter(s) in Java?
- If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T n1, T .. n2); //this is where the optional parameter comes in
}
```

The error comes from the fact that you are trying to apply the operator `+` to a Integer and an Array of Integers. The following, for instance

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T n1, T n2); //this is where the optional parameter comes in
}
```

would work fine, since you would be applying the operator `+` to two Integers.

If you want to keep the same Interface then you need to change you code in the main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator<Integer> addition = (n1, n2) -> n1 + Arrays.stream(n2).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

> Is it possible to create a generic functional interface with optional
> parameter(s) in Java?

From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters) one can read:

> varargs could do that (in a way). Other than that, all variables in
> the declaration of the method must be supplied. If you want a variable
> to be optional, you can overload the method using a signature which
> doesn't require the parameter.

That being said, what you could do is something like:

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T ...n);
}
```

In this way, the method `operation` can accept 0, 1 ... N elements and even `null`.

Then in your main:

```
Calculator<Integer> addition = n -> (n == null) ? 0 : 
                                    Arrays.stream(n).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

A running Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator<Integer> addition = n -> (n == null) ? 0 : Arrays.stream(n).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(addition.operation(1, 2));
        System.out.println(addition.operation(1));
        System.out.println(addition.operation());
        System.out.println(addition.operation(null));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 // 1 + 2
1 // 1
0 // empty array 
0 // null
```

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890963/2711488), you can implement your interface by lambda expressions processing the varargs parameters, e.g. with a Stream. But you can also design an interface for associative operations providing default methods in addition to the two argument version:

```java
interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T n1, T n2);
    default T operation(T first, T... args) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(args))
            .reduce(this::operation).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

Note that the method signature `operation(T first, T... args)` enforces that there is at least one element, which allows to use `reduce` without an identity element or fallback value for empty streams.

You can use it like

```java
Calculator<Integer> addition = (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2;
Integer sum = addition.operation(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

But the operation must be associative, like addition, multiplication, or string concatenation, etc. If you want to support non-associative operations, those operations would have to override `operation(T first, T... args)` with an appropriate implementation. Overriding it doesn’t work with lambda expressions. The alternative would be to have an interface for arbitrary calculations and a specialization for associative operations:

```java
interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T first, T... args);
}
interface AssociativeOp<T> extends Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T n1, T n2);
    @Override
    default T operation(T first, T... args) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(args))
            .reduce(this::operation).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

Then, non-associative operations can implement `Calculator<T>` via a lambda expression handling all arguments while associative operations can be implemented like:

```java
Calculator<Integer> addition = (AssociativeOp<Integer>)(n1, n2) -> n1 + n2;
```

The necessity for a type cast could be eliminated by a factory method, using type inference for its parameter. However, when we are at this point, we could remember that there is already a functional interface type for operations with two arguments which the examples are even using, implicitly. So another alternative would be:

```java
interface Calculator<T> {
    T operation(T first, T... args);

    static <U> Calculator<U> associative(BinaryOperator<U> op) {
        return (first,other) -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(other))
            .reduce(op).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

This still allows arbitrary implementations via lambda expression while associative operations can be implemented with a simplified:

```java
Calculator<Integer> addition = Calculator.associative((n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
```

(Or `Calculator.associative(Integer::sum)`)